# How to specify Metro Bundler IP adress in my React-Native dev-environment?

Tags: android, react-native, metro-bundler

Not sure if this is even possible, but here goes:

### Setup

- I have a React-Native app setup using react-native cli
- I'm trying to make network requests to my application backend

  - say, `stage.foo.com/graphql`
- I start my android emulator and start the dev-server:

```sh
react-native run-android
```

- This starts my metro-bundler dev-server at `localhost:8081`

### The Problem

- Since company `foo` has excellent infra and security, they've setup CORS to block all requests originating from `localhost`.
- However, they've also setup a public loop-back domain `local.foo.com` for just such an occasion.

  - `local.foo.com` redirects back to `localhost`
- if I access `local.foo.com/graphql`, it points to the endpoint I want
- When I access `local.foo.com:8081/debugger-ui` (the remote-debugging URL), it correctly connects to the Metro Bundler service that's running there.

### The remaining piece:

So after all this, here's my question:

- My react-native setup is configured to load the app from `locahost:8081`
- Is there a way to edit the setup to load the Application from `local.foo.com:8081` instead?

Note: This is not a problem with the application code, I need some way to change the source that the application hits when it's looking for the Metro Bundler service.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Open React Native application
2. Shake the device 2-3 times
3. Dev Settings → Debug server host -> IP address with 8081 port and reload, that's it

**In Emulator / Simulator to open Dev settings you can use the command <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>. Make sure it's not Release build (not  Signed APK)**

Comment: You can also use `avd shell input keyevent 82` on your terminal to open the dev pannel

Comment: trick of the day ...

Comment: is there a way to make this in command line at startup ? i have to put it at every run or metro doesn't connect at all :(